# Why can't I access the class internals of List<T> when I derive from it?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, list

```
class NewList<T> : List<T>
```

Why can't I access it's internals like `T[] _items`, etc?

Why aren't they protected, but private?

Should I use composition for this?

Comment: Am I missing something here? T[] _items seems to be a private member of List<T>, which cannot be access directly even without inheritance. How composition helps here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're private because the author (Microsoft) did not intend for you to access them, probably for safety reasons.

You should use composition instead of inheritance.  Make your class expose `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>` directly.

`List<T>` should never be directly exposed in a public API (this is actually specified in the design guidelines).  It should be used as an internal implementation detail only.

Comment: I don't think they are 'safety' reasons, more like 'correctness'

Comment: One of the main goals of proper api and encapsulation is a form of safety - you are protecting your own implmentation from the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` isn't designed to be a base class. You should use one of the classes in [System.Collections.ObjectModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.objectmodel.aspx) instead.

Comment: THanks, do you know why didn't MS seal the class?

Comment: That I don't know. It definitely would've made the situation much clearer, though.

Comment: @Reed: Yep, and I think the only reason it's not sealed now is it would break [bad] code that [assumed it made sense to] derives from it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I access it's internals like
>   T[] _items, etc?

Reflector says _items is private.  The underscore suggests a private member

> Why aren't they protected, but
>   private?

In the case of _items, Microsoft provides the public ToArray method.  It returns _items.

Comment: Thanks. I know that method but that would be a huge penalty for my collection, as it would create an extra collection because of accessibility.

Comment: It actually returns the underlying storage or a copy of? Does this mean if you mod the items in the ToArray-ed array, the contents of the list change?

Comment: No, it's a copy of the actual array. So your changes will not affect the original.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design, exposing members is only done when (absolutely) necessary, to let the object maintain a correct state at all times. And it is not a good idea to expose a field (_items) as protected, that would require a protected property. In this case, there already is a public property (this[])

Composition will give you even less access - no protected members either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it.  That is, what can you do with `_items` that you can't do with the `Item : T` property?  They have given you a simple, functional abstraction to the underlying array with the indexer.  It is very light weight -- all it does it check the bounds and increment the version of the list (on the setter) ...

```
var lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
lst[0].Dump(); // 1
lst.Dump(); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
lst[0] = 2;
lst.Dump(); // 2, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: I can think of at least two things: (1) Pass a list item as a `ref` parameter to outside code or methods like `Interlocked.CompareExchange`; (2) For types inheriting `List<someValueType>`, access items' individual fields (including modifying them or passing them as `ref` parameters).